# Checkstyle for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, coding-style, checkstyle

I'm looking to find something along the lines of Checkstyle for Visual Studio.  I've recently started a new gig doing .NET work and realized that coding standards here are a bit lacking.  While I'm still a young guy and far from the most experienced developer I'm trying to lead by example and get things going in the right direction.

I loved the ability to use Checkstyle with Eclipse and examine code before reviews so I'd like to do the same thing with Visual Studio.  Anyone have any good suggestions?

Another thing I'd be somewhat interested in is a plug-in for SVN that disallows check-in until the main coding standards are met.  I do not want people checking in busted code that's going to wind up in a code review.

Any suggestions at this point would be great.

Comment: So. New at the job, fairly young and you want to set coding standards. You want to be careful with this. Older, more experienced developers will be put off if you don't handle it right. My suggestion: find an ally then sell the idea to them and go to your manager together. Also keep in mind that there is a local culture that you need to understand before you go changing it.

Comment: @jcollum - Excellent point. "Coding Standards" tend to turn into religious arguments that can sometimes be bitter. And often times the things people get the most picky about do absolutely nothing to improve the code, except in a subjective way. Like, do you put your `{` on a new line or not.

Comment: Fortunately, C# comes with a set of conventions that are the de facto standard.  Just use those and a lot of pointless debate is avoided.

Comment: @Nick:  It's because people can safely go at each others' throats without anyone actually being "wrong".

@PSU_Kardi:  As jcollum says, finding an ally is a way to start - your build engineer is a good ally because if he's on board he can quietly add the reports to a build and then when you broach the argument you can pull 6 months worth of data out your butt.

Personally, I wouldn't put this out as "setting standards" or even "leading by example" - in your position I'd start using it on my code and wait for someone to notice.

Comment: My suggestion: Give it up.  The simple fact is that companies that care about that sort of thing already have it in place.  Those that don't have it, don't have it because they don't care.  Now if, several months in, they're impressed with your code and they *ask* you to share ideas, then great.  Till then, the best policy is just to keep your head down and make sure your own work is good.

Comment: When going on a coding standard crusade against an existing code base, it can also be damaging in other ways. For instance, if someone goes in and changes the style, without the functionality, it can really hurt the ability to do diffs between different file revisions and pick out what *actually* changed.

Comment: Adding coding standards is never a bad idea. When a company grows, it become harder and harder to make a standard and you'll have more and more different code everywhere. As soon as possible is better. Even if it's just to use a code analysis tools that is already configured on what the company already does in it's code. It's going to help the new users. Also, other interesting pieces of information can be looked at from analysis tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried StyleCop?

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

**Note**: This's been moved to https://github.com/StyleCop

Comment: thanks a lot, very useful - even though this answer is some time ago ;)

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: Please note that there are [ReSharper Command line tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=resharper-clt) available as well which are for free

Answer (score 6):

We use [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to enforce our coding standards.  It is free and integrates nicely with Visual Studio

Comment: could you tell me if you use stylecop's rules or if you implemented your own set of rules?
what i don't like about stylecop is that its rules aren't configurable (like in resharper) and that it kind of forces its rules upon you.. unless you want to go through the trouble of changing and maintaining the set of rules described in c# code..

Comment: For the most part we use StyleCop's rules.  There are a few that we disable.  I have not tried it, but it is possible to write custom rules using the StyleCop SDK.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.lovethedot.net/2008/05/creating-custom-rules-for-microsoft.html

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is called [Static Code Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis).

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4) is one option.  I think [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can check this kind of thing as well.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the proper term, I feel a bit silly at times not knowing the right name for stuff.

Comment: Isn't CheckStyle just for coding style? FxCop actually looks for errors and mistakes which clearly falls into static code analysis. But coding style is more token/whitespace analysis than dealing with actual code ...

Comment: I think you mean StyleCop..? FxCop only looks at IL-code (thus cannot check indentation, braces and so on), StyleCop looks at C# code.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the great tools you can use

[**FxCop**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3389F7E4-0E55-4A4D-BC74-4AEABB17997B&displaylang=en) is a code analysis tool that checks .NET managed code assemblies for conformance to the Microsoft .NET Framework Design Guidelines

---

[**ReSharper**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a refactoring and productivity plugin by JetBrains that extends native functionality of Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003, 2005 and 2008.

---

[**StyleCop**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1425) is a free static code analysis tool from Microsoft that checks C# code for conformance to StyleCop's recommended coding styles and a subset of Microsoft's .NET Framework Design Guidelines

ref: [**http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/**](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to review [StyleCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a long term supported version, I would recommend to look to Roselyn analyzers. They are the native support for Static Code Analysis with pre-configured rules, custom configs, and allow extensions.

According to the docs: “.NET compiler platform (Roslyn) analyzers inspect your C# or Visual Basic code for code quality and style issues.”

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview